# More migration paths

Tags: feature-request, migration

When doing an off topic close the only options are Meta and ELU. it would be nice to add [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange generally resists requests to add to this list (ELU was already an exception for us).  However, if there's data to support a request, we can ask for this.

The best way to approach a proposal to add to the migration list is to post a meta question for one specific site and include links to questions that either were or should have been migrated there.  If we've only ever migrated a dozen questions to Site X they're going to tell us to do that manually, but if we're sending questions to certain sites on a fairly regular basis or in volume, that's different.

My gut feeling is that ELL could be a candidate, Stack Overflow isn't, and I don't know about Academia but I'm leaning against.  Rather than any of us guessing, though, let's look at data.

Comment: This morning there was a question in the close vote que that should be migrated to SO. I spent less than 10 minutes looking at migration questions here, and found at least two meta questions talking about migrating technical questions to SO. They all thought that the other two sites would be more common. Besides they can't say yes if we don't ask.

Comment: Ah, let me clear up some possible confusion: *moderators* can migrate a question anywhere, so if you think a question belongs on SO or Academia or wherever, use a custom flag to request it.  It's helpful to also leave a comment about that if you can.  We're only talking here about the options that are offered in the "belongs on another site" close dialogue.

Comment: Perhaps this indicates that the *interface* needs to be changed. I.e., provide an "Other" option for belongs elsewhere close reason, which could then be presented for moderator attention. (It *might* be convenient if such provided to the moderator information about the voter's qualification for recommending the migration [e.g., rep. on recommended site, perhaps also considering vote count, question view count, and visit days for active lurkers, even "read on-topic help page" might be useful information].) Flagging for moderator attention is not an obvious choice.